Same username, with different capitalization?
Until today I was unaware that it was possible for 2 users to have the exact same username with different capitalizations .
I came across a user who probably changed their username to PhDStudent. This user has been a member for 5 months.
It is a bit confusing since my username is phdstudent.
So this entire convo can be hard to follow if you do not understand it's two different users:
Uncertainty on volatility prediction using GARCH(1,1)

Stack Exchange allows identical display name. The only unique thing is the user ID before the display name in the URL.
animuson's (staff) explanation on Are usernames required to be unique?

They're not usernames; they're display names. There's a big difference. A username is generally a unique string that identifies a user in the system. Stack Exchange doesn't use those; they use OpenID providers and a simple ID number. Your display name is merely an alternate string that more accurately represents who you are, and are rarely ever unique. They usually allow users to utilize a wider variety of characters, as well.

